# Locating a single value in a dynamically created array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a dynamic array.  The reason I need to use a dynamic array is because I don't know how many variables will need to be in the array at the start.

After the array exists, I want to parse through the ranges in the array, and at times isolate only a single cell value for one of the ranges.  Unfortunately, i'm getting an Object Required error.

I've checked already on this site and others, and I can't find an explanation.  Perhaps people are calling the actions something differently.

```
Sub get_val()

'get the number of rows
Dim id As Worksheet
Set id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ID Sheet")
rc = id.Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", After:=id.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

'Find which ones have "yes" in column Q and create an array
Dim memcache As Variant
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
ReDim memcache(x)
For i = 3 To rc
    If id.Cells(i, 17).Value = "Yes" Then
        ReDim Preserve memcache(x)
        memcache(x) = id.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
```

' Here's where i'm running into issues.
'If I want to copy one of the ranges to a another range on the sheet, that works fine

```
id.Range("A50:M50").Value = memcache(2) 'this works
```

'However, if i want to just locate one cell's value in the range it won't 'work.  This produces an "Object Required" error.

```
Debug.Print memcache(2).Cells(1, 2).Value
```

'For comparison, creating a single range will work

```
Dim cellrange As Variant

Set cellrange = id.Range("A9:M19")


Debug.Print cellrange.Cells(1, 2).Value ' this will work


End Sub
```

I would like to be able to get the value of cells (1,2) in each range saved in the array, and if they match a certain condition, I will then be updating another range on the sheet with the full range in that saved array.

Comment: `memcache` is an array and `Cells` in this case is a property of a range. Perhaps `memcache(2)(1,2)` might work.

Comment: Ok. Though a better approach would be a 2d array.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll take a look a 2d arrays.  I'm really just a novice at VBA, so I didn't even know those existed.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and ranges are different things in VBA. An array is simply an array of values, whereas a range is a reference to a group of cells on a worksheet. In this case, `Memcache` is an array, but you're trying to treat it like a range. `Memcache` does not have any cells, it just has values.

What you want is to replace `Debug.Print memcache(2).Cells(1, 2).Value` with `Debug.Print memcache(2)`.

The difference is more clear if you explicitly set your variable types, for example:

```
Dim memcache() As String '(or integer, or whatever type of data you're putting into it)
Dim cellrange As Range
```

Comment: Thank you, Josh.

Unfortunately, Debug.Print memcache(2) doesn't work.   I understand that Ranges and Arrays aren't the same.  I think my problem is that I'm trying to treat Arrays like a List in Python, which can hold different data structures.